# Liferay Service Builder Autoincrement With Counter

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I am using liferay service builder jar for each plugin portlet. So when i have to insert a new record. I am using below code to insert the record.

```
XXX xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXX(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(XXX.class.getName()));
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

Each table has a primary key with auto increment. But counter local service util will calculate its own counter value. I need each insert's primary key value. But in this case if first record is insert. 1 will be insert for the record but liferay counter will return 101 or 201 according to deployment.

This works fine

```
XXX xxx = new XXXImpl();
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

I got the exact key as per hibernate. But i can not use this. Because i am using jar file of service builder and there is not Impl class.

Service Builder xml file:

```
<entity name="XXX" local-service="true"
remote-service="false">
<column name="id" type="long" id-type="increment" primary="true"></column> 
<column name="value" type="String" ></column></entity>
```

Another approach to explain:

Hi,
I am using service builder to my all plugin portlets. And i have custom table having primary key with autoincrement. 
As of now i know there are these ways to insert records to table.

```
XXX xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXX(0); 
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

OR

```
XXX xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXX(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment()); // Global increment
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

OR

```
XXX xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXX(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment(XXX.class.getName())); // Increment table specific
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

In first if i want to get promary key value i gets 0, second long value, third incremented value wrt table name.
I am using thid one. Now if i re-deploy the service or portlet counter value will be incresed 101,201,...
And this can be handled by setting counter.increment.xxx.Class=1 or counter.increment=1.

But i just want to get database table incremented value from "xxx". So there is any way to do this.
Like this:

```
XXX xxx = new XXXImpl();
xxx.setValue(value);
XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

Here i can get the value which i want from database table.

Comment: This might be the same non-issue as has been discussed in length here: https://web.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/87442314

Comment: @OlafKock, There is not issue with liferay and code. But i need same value which is in database table. If i am using counterlocalserviceutil it will give its own incremented value but table will increment by 1 with its own value. There will always a mismatch.

Comment: You might not need to give an id at all to `create`: The `add` method might set its own id, which will be (most of the times, unless something preempts it) one more than you set before. I hope you're not using DB-autoincrement fields with ServiceBuilder. (Note: "issue" was not meant to be read as "bug", just "non-issue" was assumed as the linked post worried about id semantics)

Comment: @OlafKock, Thanks for quick response and help. I have added the service builder. I agree that we don't need id while creating the record. I have an example. Liferay starts with 1 counter for entity. When we redeploy the portlet it will increase by 100 and next value will be 101. And in my case when i insert the value using CounterLocalServiceUtil it will give me 101. But in database table it will insert with its own value+1. So if there was 0 autoincrenment value in my in table then it gives 1. Hope you understand what i am saying. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
XXX xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.createXXX(0); 
xxx.setValue(value);
xxx = XXXLocalServiceUtil.addXXX(xxx);
```

Now we have the incremented value in xxx. We just have to re-assign the object.